# What to do after becoming free from suffering and attachments?

Tags: teaching, suffering, attachment, stream-entry, sotapanna

Suppose I'm free from suffering, free from attachments, untouched by pain and pleasure, with absolute, constant calm and peace of mind; feeling profound compassion towards all beings (from an ant, to my mother, to a murderer).

I no longer see any vexation in front of me. There's nothing to fix. There's nothing to overcome. There's nothing to attain. (I'm not really interested in enligthenment).

What would you recommend me to do? Is there a way to make good use of this state, maybe to help others somehow? What would you do in my place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply cultivate what you've reached and help others to find their very own path accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing is left for attainment. Why would you ask anyone else to tell you to do , is this still not a form of an attachment to views of others ?

If someone is not interested in enlightenment or if it is not achieved then in particular ,  they would consider to promote and propagate  compassion and kindness amongst beings so that it could lead to path of partial fulfilment of end of suffering.

Comment: But I didn't say I have nothing to learn! :)

Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

In the Mahayana tradition, liberation is a step on the path to full enlightenment. To become a fully enlightened buddha, practice generosity, morality, patience, enthusiasm, meditation, and wisdom (the 6 perfections).

Answer (score 0):

what to do after getting rid off suffering and attachment is the question and answer to this is as follows.
   at that stage no such question will arise bcs the driving force behind doing something will also be ceased. the sankharas (prime movers for actions )will be nil. Upon this no any type of doing will happen except those which happens out of outburst of unconditional compassion. In our day to day life also we experience that if we are compassionate for a slight second of time towards any being in some or other pathetic condition, it is observed that, that being starts changing /improving. after liberated state, only compassion works .there remains no self to generate such question as what to do now ?